What's the minimum regularity needed for Picard−Lindelöf?
Consider a system of first-oder ODEs of the form
$$
 \dot{x}(t) = \sum_{i = 1}^n f_i(t) V_i(x)
$$
where $V_i$ are Lipschitz continuous functions $V_i: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ on some open $U ⊆ \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f_i ∈ L^1([0, 1])$.
Now the standard Picard−Lindelöf theorem is usually formulated for ODEs with continuous right-hand sides, which this is not, but looking at the proof (e.g. wikipedia) it seems like every steps still works with small modifications, giving short-time existence and uniqueness.
Does anyone know a reference for this fact, or something more general?
Rmk: More generally, it seems to me that the standard proof needs the "right hand side" function $F(t, x)$ to be locally in $L^1([0, 1]; C^{0, 1}(U))$, i.e.\ the Lipschitz constant is integrable.
